# ZERO_RESULTS from Google Search API "findplacefromtext"

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-places-api, file-get-contents

Facing a weird behavior while using Google Place API "findplacefromtext". https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json

When the API is used through browser to check the response. Valid response is shown. Screenshot attached. [image]

While when the API is used through `CURL on Linux Terminal` or `CURL in PHP` or `file_get_contents` in PHP the response is :

```
{
   "candidates" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Here is the Google API. "API KEY" is not shared for security reasons:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?key=APIKEY&inputtype=textquery&fields=photos,formatted_address,name,rating,opening_hours,geometry,reference,place_id&input=Lollapalooza+Argentina+Mart%C3%ADnez+Argentina

The API Key is valid and properly authorized.

What can be the reason behind the change of response ?

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me.

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?key=APIKEY&inputtype=textquery&fields=photos,formatted_address,name,rating,opening_hours,geometry,reference,place_id&input=Lollapalooza+Argentina+Mart%C3%ADnez+Argentina";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print '<pre>';
print $response;
print '</pre>';
```

Which prints:

```
{
   "candidates" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "Martínez, Buenos Aires Province, Argentina",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -34.4811677,
               "lng" : -58.5165812
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -34.47967187010728,
                  "lng" : -58.5156313
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -34.48237152989272,
                  "lng" : -58.51943089999999
               }
            }
         },
         "name" : "Lollapalooza Argentina",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1536,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115749286027841945795\"\u003eA Google User\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAiIyTEnkgKjKYFyQZKesopF4_dwAP6h0ynKq0nO5e9AelAo9D0IPqASptGAbZ999ZcOfPIQnlQYie5KtO45bIkSAMOowBkROYcJLdntbS0WhsNhhQJaG5lxU8aCUTuyjGEhBnHL_HnTImzwkwS4OHVSN9GhRO_IGFKamDj_8OEIL3i9MGaCWsXQ",
               "width" : 2048
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJg-5cj9SxvJURkm6B2DlkKL0",
         "rating" : 5,
         "reference" : "ChIJg-5cj9SxvJURkm6B2DlkKL0"
      },
      {
         "formatted_address" : "Av. Sta Fe 1, B1642 Martínez, Buenos Aires, Argentina",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -34.4742948,
               "lng" : -58.51265829999999
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -34.47292497010727,
                  "lng" : -58.51127897010728
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -34.47562462989271,
                  "lng" : -58.51397862989273
               }
            }
         },
         "name" : "Lollapalooza Argentina",
         "place_id" : "ChIJUQmrWaqxvJURScOzSiIIk9o",
         "rating" : 0,
         "reference" : "ChIJUQmrWaqxvJURScOzSiIIk9o"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is due to the difference in IP address from the originating machine performing the request.

To prove this, change from an IP bias to an area and both machines/browser/php script should return the same data set.

See more:

> **locationbias** — Prefer results in a specified area, by specifying
> either a radius plus lat/lng, or two lat/lng pairs representing the
> points of a rectangle. If this parameter is not specified, the API
> uses IP address biasing by default.
>
> IP bias: Instructs the API to use IP address biasing. Pass the string
> **ipbias** (this option has no additional parameters).

Source: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search